# How to run external msbuild file from cruise control .net

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I have an msbuild xml file that builds about 20 vc2010 solutions. It retrieves the code from source control, builds all the solutions, and obfuscates the results (for the .net projects). I'd like to use this from ccnet. Is there a way to just 'call' this xml file to build my projects? Are there disadvantages to doing it this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, CruiseControl.NET has a [task for building MSBuild projects](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/MsBuild_Task).

Comment: Yes, but it appears to take a vc solution as the project file. Can it use an existing .xml build script as the project?

Comment: MSBuild will build sln or .proj files. If you call it with no project or solution then it will build the first sln or project file it finds.

Comment: Ah...it just dawned on me. A .sln file **is** an msbuild project. I'll give this a try.

Comment: fyi - not long after this, I switched to using Jenkins. It's dead simple and works well.